# Welcome file Jsp

Tags: css, jsp

I have configured home.jsp to welcome file in web.xml
when I run the application there is no problem in CSS Design
But when I call home.jsp through link the CSS are Not Found

Application Architecture is:

```
WebContent
|
jsp
.....home.jsp
.....contact.jsp
|
css
|
.....style.css
WEB_INF
| 
.....lib
.....Web.xml
```

in web.xml file in have written 
`<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>jsp/home.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>`

i am calling from contact.jsp like  Home

Comment: "i am calling from contact.jsp like Home" - could you elaborate this? what do you mean?

Comment: checkout the html source code generated in both ways, source code may help you to find the error, or post your source code if possible

Comment: Please show the part of your JSP where you refer to the CSS. Also, you could take a look of the generated HTML output in your browser, there you see the link to the CSS as well.

Comment: i am calling home.jsp as <a herf="../jsp/home.jsp">home</a>